# How does one specify a custom search path with Browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I have a large project that consists of hundreds of source files broken into several folders.

Something like this:

```
src/
  AAA.js
  subdir/
    DDD.js
```

I would like to be able to specify dependencies with non-relative paths.

For instance, in `DDD.js` I would like to do this:

```
var AAA = require('AAA');
```

...rather than this:

```
var AAA = require('../AAA');
```

How can I achieve this with Browserify?

Comment: You can't: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify/issues/170

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify), Browserify uses [`browser-resolve`](https://npmjs.org/package/browser-resolve) under the hood.

When using the node API (as opposed to the CLI), you can specify a `paths` option which contains a list of directories to pass to `browser-resolve`.

The solution for my example would thus be something like this:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var b = browserify({
  paths: [
    __dirname + '/src'
  ]
});

b.add(__dirname + '/src/AAA.js');
b.bundle().pipe(process.stdout);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or if you want to do it from the command line you can add your directory to the node search path:

```
NODE_MODULES=$NODE_MODULES:src browserify -o output.js input.js
```

Comment: Somehow this isn't working for me, and I still don't know how to add paths when using command line.

Comment: @Papipo check this out https://github.com/substack/browserify-handbook#custom-paths. Use the `NODE_PATH` environment variable.